# R programming - difference between using lapply and a simple function

Tags: r

**I'm not sure that I understand the different outputs in these two scenarios:**

(1)

```
 pioneers <- c("GAUSS:1777", "BAYES:1702", "PASCAL:1623", "PEARSON:1857")
 split <- strsplit(pioneers, split = ":")
 split
```

(2)

```
pioneers <- c("GAUSS:1777", "BAYES:1702", "PASCAL:1623", "PEARSON:1857")
split <- lapply(pioneers, strsplit, split = ":")
split
```

In both cases, the output is a list but I'm not sure when I'd use the one notation (simply applying a function to a vector) or the other (using lapply to loop the function over the vector).

Thanks for the help.

Greg

Comment: I think it partly depends on the function you want to apply. If it can handle vectors, you can do `myfun(myvector)`. If it doesn't, you can use lapply.

Comment: In this particular case, I'm not sure when you'd ever need to do the latter (it creates a more cumbersome structure to work with IMO). One usually `lapply`s on the result of a `strsplit`. Also, R has a `split` function (`lapply` with `strsplit` like that). Also, while it's smart enough to distinguish between your use of `split` as a variable name vs the built-in function, stomping on the namespace could make it difficult to debug issues (like when you accidentally assign `split` to something but meant to assign the output of a call to `split` to something).

Comment: `strsplit` is a vectorized function, i.e. it can work on a whole vector, applying the split to each element, so you wouldn't need `lappply` here. You would use `lapply` on the resulting list if you wanted to modify/exrtact something of the resulting list, for example to extract the the second element of each list element, you could use `lapply(split, "[", 2)` (where `split` is the result of `strsplit(pioneers, split = ":")`.

Answer (score 2):

To me it's to do with how the output is returned. `[l]apply` stands for list apply - i.e. the output is returned as a list. `strsplit` already returns a list as, if there were multiple `:`s in your `pioneers` vector, it's the only data structure that makes sense - i.e. a list element of each of the 4 elements of the vector and each list element contains a vector of the split string.

So using `lapply(x, strsplit, ...)` will always return a list inside a list, which you probably don't want in this case.

Using `lapply` is useful in cases where you expect the result of the function you're applying to be a vector of an undefined or variable length. As `strsplit` can see this coming already, the use of `lapply` is redundant, so you should probably know what form you expect/want your answer to be in, and use the appropriate functions to coerce the output in to the right data structure.

To make clear, the output of the examples you gave is not the same. One is a list, one is a list of lists. The identical result would be

`lapply(pioneers, function(x, split) strsplit(x, split)[[1]], split = ":")`

i.e. taking the first list element of the inner list (which is only 1 element anyway) in each case.

Comment: Thanks - that helps a lot.